# NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Tags: python, undefined, mqtt

I don't have any experience with python... but I need to use it for (raspberry+mqtt+wiringpi)+home_assistance integration, I would like to create simple action, mqtt client is listening, and while receive proper information at proper topic, he will change wiringpi setting... what partially works... the issue came when I try to create dependency on the information.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt #import the client1
import wiringpi
import time

wiringpi.wiringPiSetup()

############
def wiadomosc(client, userdata, message):
    global external_value1, added_value2
    print("message received " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    print("message topic=",message.topic)
    print("message qos=",message.qos)
    print("message retain flag=",message.retain)
external_value1 = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
wiringpi.pinMode(29, 0)
########################################
broker_address="192.168.0.211"
print("creating new instance")
client = mqtt.Client("P1") #create new instance
client.on_message=wiadomosc #attach function to callback
print("connecting to broker")
client.connect(broker_address) #connect to broker
client.loop_start() #start the loop
print("Subscribing to topic","home/kitchen/output/lights/set")
client.subscribe("home/kitchen/output/lights/set")
time.sleep(40000) # wait
client.loop_stop() #stop the loop
```

I'm receiving

```
NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

I know that message will show-up when it will be received from mqtt... I tried to create empty value, but it did not worked properly, code above is simplified, I have removed all "if", and only left the part which is causing issue

Comment: `external_value1 = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))` message is not defined,you are calling something from a function that doesn't exist.

Comment: but It will be created when I will receive a message from mqtt... how should I create dependency on something that will be created ?

Comment: A row of hashes doesn't denote the end of a function, *indentation* does.

Comment: you can create it as empty then fill it with the new data from your  `mqtt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is indentation, `message` is out of your function. You're passing `message`as a parameter of `wiadomosc()` function, but right after the deceleration of this function, initializing `external_value1` with `message.payload` which is not defined before.

```
def wiadomosc(client, userdata, message):
    global external_value1, added_value2
    print("message received " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    print("message topic=",message.topic)
    print("message qos=",message.qos)
    print("message retain flag=",message.retain)
    external_value1 = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
wiringpi.pinMode(29, 0)
```